# Is it secure to host Django Admin media on a public folder on AWS

Tags: python, django, security, heroku

I have a Django app hosted in the cloud (Heroku if that makes a difference though I can't see how) and am looking to move all static content to AWS (images, CSS etc).

Is it secure to have Django's Admin media (ie the media/ css/ and js/ folders) hosted on a publicly accessible site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be.

After all, when you login to the admin panel, the links to the css and js are always public. Meaning at that point they are just like any other static resource and they don't require to be logged in order to view them. So you can store them whenever you want and as long as they will remain read-only to the public (which it is in AWS), there should not be any security risk.